# I can't save audio file after recordings in Android application development

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio, android-activity

After working on a sound recorder, I discovered that the files are not saving..  But the code is right.. With error that directory is not found..  But I created a script to make a new directory if it's not available.. But it's not working..  I have included the code here..  Someone should just help...

```
  private String getFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_WAV);
}

private String getTempFilename() {
    String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
    File file = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }

    File tempFile = new File(filepath, AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
    if (tempFile.exists())
        tempFile.delete();
    return (file.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + AUDIO_RECORDER_TEMP_FILE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was how i did and i works for me

//uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"

//uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

```
private MediaRecorder mr;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mr = new MediaRecorder();

    mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mr.setOutputFile("/sdcard/_name.3gp");
    mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    try{
        mr.prepare();
        mr.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex){

    }
}

public void stopAndSave(View v){

    try{
        mr.stop();
        mr.release();

    }
    catch (Exception ex){

    }
}
```

Comment: Not yet..  My full code is different from urs...  I'll like to modify it a bit..  But could u please post ur full code let me see and understand?

Comment: Or send it to my mail? Kingo4luv@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks.. I have gotten the class..  And I also send mine... U can help me check mine..  Am working on a project right now

Comment: Please check ur mail

Comment: yaap yaap, i see it. you wrote in good manner, i like it, i have the following exception when am trying to open my android studio, i will be back to you once i solve this        ./programming/android-studio/bin/../jre/bin/java: 9: ./programming/android-studio/bin/../jre/bin/java: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Answer (score 0):

Have you added user permission to use external storage in app 
It's done like this in AndroidManifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: I have added permission